# sort .map data in react js (show latest date on top)

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-native

I am trying to sort data according to date where the latest date must come at top of the list

```
let mapped = predefined.reduce((r, a) => {
   r[a.date] = [...(r[a.date] || []), a];
   return r;
 }, {});
```

I tried mapping like this

`mapped` has the list of data but when I call `the item.date` nothing is printing

```
{Object.values(mapped).map((item, index) => (
                  <tr style={styles.tr}>
                    <td>{item.date}</td>
                    <td>
                      {item.criticality == "high risk" ? (
                        <button
                          //   onClick={() => findgraph(user.id)}
                          style={styles.red}
                        ></button>
                      ) : item.criticality == "stable" ? (
                        <button
                          //   onClick={() => findgraph(user.id)}
                          style={styles.green}
                        ></button>
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          //   onClick={() => findgraph(user.id)}
                          style={styles.yellow}
                        ></button>
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button>view</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
```

code sandbox with data

Comment: well for starters, as you want to sort the data, you have to use [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method instead of `.map` or `.reduce`. Try it once by yourself

Comment: can you add sample data for `predefined` to the question?

Comment: In this case, `mapped` will be something like so: `{date1: [{date: date1}], date2: [{date: date2}], ...}`. So, when one iterates over `Object.values(mapped)`, it is really iterating over: `[[{date: date1}], [{date: date2}]], ...` <--- this is an array of array (of objects with prop `date`). So, `item[0].date` should help accesss the `date` prop at index-0 of `item`.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera i have added a codesandbox with data .feel free to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DD-MM-YYYY` format is not identified by `new Date()` and returned `Invalid Date` as it checks the `DD` place for a month and when `DD` is greater than 12 it fails. Had to use a simple util function to do the string to date conversion.

Try like below.

Util function to convert date properly.

```
  const getDateObjectFromString = (dateString) => {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split("-");
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  };
```

In your `useEffect` to load the data do `sort` and set the values.

```
const predefinedData = res.data;

predefinedData.sort(({ date: firstDate }, { date: secondDate }) => {
  return (
    getDateObjectFromString(secondDate) -
    getDateObjectFromString(firstDate)
  );
});

setpredefined(predefinedData);
```

[image: Edit winter-architecture-vg75km]

Comment: @jisa ks, check this out !!